# Reboot Azure WebRole Instance from it's own running instance

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have Azure WebRole and I have to change its System Locale dynamically.
For that, I tried to reboot instance in WebRole Start-up task with Windows `shutdown -r` command
and it works.

But after the reboot, I can't connect to the instance with Remote desktop.
(like the load balancer doesn't work...)
I guess I need to use some Azure management functions to reboot formally.

In this situation, Which way should I take to reboot itself simply?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try [RequestRecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.requestrecycle.aspx)

Comment: @JimO'Neil I'm pretty sure `RequestRecycle` does *not* reboot the VM.

Comment: Thank you! I tried RequestRecycle, but no action taken in spite of no error.

Answer (score 2):

`shutdown -r` should work fine. I've used it quite a bit.

I couldn't find a good code snippet for you, but Wade does a reboot in his startup task here: http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/using-expression-encoder-4-in-a-windows-azure-worker-role/

The reboot in that example is an effect of another command he runs, but it works the same way.

Comment: Thank you! I tried that Wade showed us, using ServerManagerCMD.exe with -restart option. but I still cannnot connect to the instance after the reboot. ServerManagerCMD is not component of Azure, so the effect is same as shutdown -r,I presume.

Comment: Are you sure your startup task isn't just rebooting over and over in a loop (on every boot)?

Comment: Thanks. Not repeating. I managed it, or ServerManagerCMD doesn't reboot if the specified component was already installed. Deploying role(from Azure portal) completed normally, but I cannot make RDP connection. then doing restart role from Azure portal, RDP is OK!

Comment: So, My Web Application works fine and no problem for automatic updates or initializing instance by Azure center. RDP is the only problem. thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. This has always just worked for me. What happens when you try to RDP? Does it time out? Or give an error?

Comment: Oh! Is this way working for you? My RDP request ends with like "couldn't connect. cause of remote computer not running, disable configuration, etc.". But I found that disabling remote access and re-enabling remote access for the role on Azure portal works fine. Even during the process, Web application is available with multi-instance. Thanks!

Comment: @ms-skr This definitely sounds like a bug to me, and probably a regression. You may want to contact Windows Azure support.

Comment: I found new things! Sending web request to App once after deploying or initializing with "shutdown -r (on start-up)" may be effective. Then I could connect RDP. I have no idea for the reason, but it works fine several times. Many thanks!

Comment: @smarx: This is still a problem.  I found this post from April: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/2820829b-6e9d-4d1d-b259-7acc9aed7b81/rdp-become-unavailable-after-instance-reboot, and our team is having the exact same issue.  In fact, I can reproduce it by simply issuing "shutdown /r /t 1" from a command prompt on a running instance, and when the instance comes back up, RDP is not accessible.  However, if I simply reboot the instance *again* from the Windows Azure Portal, RDP works again.

Comment: I have posted an Azure Support Ticket with the issue and will followup with any results.  Related: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/2820829b-6e9d-4d1d-b259-7acc9aed7b81/rdp-become-unavailable-after-instance-reboot

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed with Microsoft Azure Support Team that this is a bug in Windows 2008 SP2 instances.  If you can upgrade to either Windows 2008 R2 (osFamily=2), or Windows 2012 (osFamily=3) instances, the issue is resolved in those OS versions.